# Bootstrap tabs are overlapping in smaller devices

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap theme and working mostly fine for rest of the layouts. But the tabs do not look fit in smaller screens.
The source:
[image]

And the output in bigger/normal screens:
[image]

Then the output in the smaller screen goes like this:
[image]

I do not have specific extra JS fro the tabs.

Hope someone can give a rigth direction.

By the way I am just a biginner on CSS stuffs and bootstrap too.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the responsive utilities bootstrap provides to show/hide elements based on screen sizes.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs hidden-xs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked visible-xs-block">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can use http://www.bootply.com/new# to test this out (copy and paste the code above, run it, then resize your browser to a narrow width to see it in action.)

You may need to rethink how certain things are presented on the page at the different sizes but this should give you some tools when you need to present different elements based on screen size (responsive.)

Comment: Well that sounds a good trick, will give it a try and get back to you. Thank you.